# Best practice for accessing google cloud instances externally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So, I need to have several google compute instances accessible from the outside and preferably with DNS names to make things simplier.

However, when creating a DNS record I need to enter a fixed IP and this means that I need to use a static external IP address as far as I can tell. Since using an ephemeral address would result in the DNS record pointing to the wrong IP after a reboot.

Problem is that external addresses seems really scarce. Quota is only 7! I suppose I can try to request for an increase but the low quota makes me think that it may exist some other way of doing this.

Is there some other "best practice" for accessing instances except using static IP addresses? Such as using forwarding rules etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special here. You can request as many external IP addresses as you need. You can try to minimize the amount of external IP addresses required by using Network or HTTP/S load balancer if you need to send traffic to multiple identical instance groups.

Comment: He's not looking for an answer; he knows it already. He want's an industry guideline on the best practices; more likely then not it's because sloppiness on the cloud will usually end up costing you a LOT OF MONEY.

Comment: Its ok. I'm happy with the answer. I was just afraid I had missed something very simple feature in google cloud. Now I can just use static ips with a clear conscience

Answer (score 0):

Cisco published a paper on IP usage best practices in the cloud. You can find it here:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/cloud-systems-management/prime-network-registrar/white_paper_c11-728639.html#_Toc361087504

**The section relevant to your question is:**

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/cloud-systems-management/prime-network-registrar/white_paper_c11-728639.html#_Toc361087504

Comment: You can also request more static IPs; Google does not charge you extra for them as long as they are in use.

Comment: Thanks for link. Seems a bit overkill for me though :)